# How and where to call a jquery method in a form binded with master page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to call a jquery method. I am using the master pages in the project. I want to know exactly how and where implement the jquery.

Code snippets in a from:

```
 <asp:Content ID="cntRegistration" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID=cphBase>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upRegistration" runat="server">

<ContentTemplate>

<table width=100% height=100%  bordercolor="blue">

<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" text=”testjquery”></asp:TextBox>

</table>

</ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>

</asp:Content>
```

Queries:

1. Where to call the .js files, in master page or in a form? [I hope it should be in the master page, is it right?]
2. Where to write the scripsts in a form? Is it between the asp:content and  asp:updatepanel? Can explain exact place to put the scripts?

   Script Code snippets:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {

       $("#txtNoOfMales").change(function () {

           var ticketRequired = this.value;

           var options = {

               type: "POST",

               url: "Register.aspx/GetAvailableTicketsForMales",

               data: "{no:" + ticketRequired + "}",

               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

               dataType: "json",

               success: function (response) {

                   if (response.d != "") {

                       alert(response.d);

                       $("#txtNoOfMales").focus();

                   }

               }
   });
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the answers:

1. In the master page. head tag, as it is included by every page that uses the master
2. You can write them in the content area by adding a script tag

One thing to remember: The elements in the content page will change their ids at runtime. Thus, a textbox named "txtOne" maybe become "xxx_txtOne". Watch out for that :)